# How do i make the string of "loading" repeat

Tags: python, string, repeat

So I'm working on a project at school and I'm wondering how to make certain strings repeat. As an example, I made a small piece of code that has a string to that could be repeated. How do I repeat the string "loading..."? (Obviously, half the code is missing as this is just an example!)

```
import sys
import time
print("Welcome to the loading screen of every game!!!")
yesNo = input("Do you want to continue(Y or N): ").upper()
if yesNo == "Y":
    print("Loading...")
    time.sleep(10)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you want it to repeat, using a loop would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
for i in range(5):
    print("Loading...")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: ThankYou! Its just small things like that which I forget

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what you mean by "repeat"? If I understand the meaning of your code snippet correctly, you want "Loading..." to keep printing as long as the user is entering a "Y"?

This is a great use for a [while loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)! I would recommend putting it into an infinite loop (`while True`) and then `break` out when a certain condition has been satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a `while` statement or `for` statement.

Also I would assume you would only want it to do this for a certain amount of time and not infinitely in which case [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) might also be useful.

**Method 1: using `for`:**

```
for i in range(5):
    print("Loading...")
    time.sleep(10)
```

This output would be:

```
Loading...
Loading...
Loading...
Loading...
Loading...
```

**Method 2:  using `while`:**

```
 i = 5
 while i < 5:
     print("Loading...")
     time.sleep(10)
     i = i + 1
```

This output will be:

```
Loading...
Loading...
Loading...
Loading...
```

**Method 3: infinite looping:**

```
 while True:
     print("Loading...")
     time.sleep(10)
```

This will keep printing "Loading..." forever.